# Spark-Java : Nested loops and Actions over elements in RDD

Tags: java, apache-spark, nested-loops, rdd

I have set of elements in RDD say

RDD1 = [4,7,8,9]

Calculate the mean of RDD as below

`xbar = RDD1.mean();`

From the values in RDD, xbar(mean) value is 7

Now am trying to calculate summation of  (x[i] - xbar)*(x[j]-xbar) for i!=j
(say x[i] represents element in RDD )
The below code is normal java version of this summation calculation

```
for(int i=0;i<n;i++) {
       for(int j=0;j<n;j++) {
           if(i != j) {
               temp1 = x.get(i) - xbar;
               temp2 = x.get(j) - xbar;
               num = num + (w[i][j]) * temp1 * temp2 ;

           } 
       }
}
```

here n is no:of elements and w[i][j] is nxn matrix

So can you please suggest me how to perform these kind of nested loops

Comment: Check out cartesian to generate the matrix then run the fold.

Comment: I have tried cartesian also but got confused with doing next steps.

Answer (score 1):

I hope a Scala answer works for you. It's the same with Java, I'm just not familiar with the Java API.

If you can hold `w` (an N×N array) in memory, then this is not a big data problem, and you should not be using Apache Spark. So I'm going to assume `w` is not an array in memory, but an RDD. Maybe it's a sparse matrix! (If not, just use a plain `join` instead of `leftOuterJoin`.)

```
// rdd1 has N elements.
// w represents an N×N sparse matrix indexed by coordinates.
def f(rdd1: RDD[Double],
      w: RDD[((Long, Long), Double)]): Double = {
  val mean = rdd1.mean
  val deviations = rdd1.map(_ - mean)
  val indexed = deviations.zipWithIndex
  // This "cartesian" results in an RDD with N×N elements!
  val deviationPairs = indexed.cartesian(indexed).map {
    case ((d1, i1), (d2, i2)) => ((i1, i2), (d1, d2))
  }
  val weighted = deviationPairs.leftOuterJoin(w).map {
    case ((i1, i2), ((d1, d2), wOpt)) =>
      val w = wOpt.getOrElse(1.0) // Whatever default value you want.
      w * d1 * d2
  }
  weighted.sum
}
```